# translate LDAP from LdapCtxFactory to Spring ldap

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ldap

The following function authenticates my user successfully. I have been trying to convert this code into Spring XML with an "ldap-authentication-provider" but so far no success (authentication returns an error, which I cannot debug/log).

```
public void auth(String user, String password)
{

    try
    {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://172.18.0.240:389");
        // 
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "PFA\\"+user);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

        // Create the initial context

        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        boolean result = ctx != null;

        if(ctx != null)
            ctx.close();

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {           
        return false;
    }
}
```

In theory (using the tutorials all around the web) it should look something like this:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/auth" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/dashboard" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/auth" 
        default-target-url="/dashboard" 
        authentication-failure-url="/auth?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/auth?logout" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
     <ldap-authentication-provider user-dn-pattern="uid=PFA\\{0}"/>
</authentication-manager>


<ldap-server url="ldap://172.18.0.240:389/" />

</beans:beans>
```

if in stead of LDAP i the following authentication, it works just fine:

```
<authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
        <user name="peter" password="verysecurepassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service>
</authentication-provider>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

After getting some more information about the active directory we use I have edited the XML:

```
<authentication-manager>
     <ldap-authentication-provider user-search-filter="(uid={0})"
      user-search-base="ou=Company"/>
</authentication-manager>


<ldap-server url="ldap://172.18.0.240:389/dc=pfa,dc=local" />
```

the full path to my own user is: pfa.local/Company/Users Company/Office/Suboffice/

When I try to login now I get the following error message:

Reason: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C09072B, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580]; remaining name 'ou=Company'

This seems to have to do with being able to query the active directory. However with the LdapCtxFactory example this was not needed. Can I get around this ?

Comment: What is the error, can you show the stack-trace?

Comment: There is no error displayed, but the page is forwarded to "auth?error" which means authentication failed.

Comment: when i remove my custom login page I do get the following error message: "Your login attempt was not successful, try again.

Reason: Bad credentials"
Since the same credentials work with the LdapCtxFactory, there must be something wrong in de xml

Answer (score 0):

With your updated config and updated error code it looks like you need fix the binding and "ou" is missing in configuration.

Check the [Spring configuration of LDAP authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/LdapAuthenticationProvider.html) and the post "[Spring Security AD LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975309/spring-security-ad-ldap-error-code-1-000004dc-ldaperr-dsid-0c0906e8)"

Comment: You are suggesting that I do the 3 steps as provided in the post you linked. But I would like to authenticate the user directly without the manager credentials. It was possible with the DOMAIN/user login method. Is this still possible with Spring?