# SpringBoot + Spring Security + LDAP login without UID

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap

I am new to LDAP, and I am trying to figure out how to use spring security with ldap for login. All the examples/guides/tutorials that I read, are using the UID as a log in form. I have no UID.

This is the structure: 
[LDAP structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtSPa.jpg)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends  WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("mail={0},ou=group")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=group")
            .contextSource()
            .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=ad,dc=company,dc=com")
            .and()
            .passwordCompare()
            .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
            .passwordAttribute("userPassword");

}
```

Here I tried to replace the UID with MAIL , but it does not work. 
error:

```
Reason: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0907C2, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580]; remaining name 'mail=erik.zs@mail.com, '
```

I hope someone knows how to add login without UID, thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Security AD LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975309/spring-security-ad-ldap-error-code-1-000004dc-ldaperr-dsid-0c0906e8) TLDR: you might need to bind to LDAP with an admin account before attempting the search, as Spring LDAP does a search behind the scenes for authentication

Comment: I have the permission to search with my account, but I do not have access to an Admin account...
EDIT: Let's say that I recieved an admin account, where and how I should do the binding?

Comment: Putting it into an answer, for better readability

Answer (score 1):

Putting it into an answer, since it involves code blocks now, and these don't work well with the comments.

As discussed above in comments, your problem is that Spring uses LdapTemplate for LDAP access, which uses LDAP search for all authentication calls. Searching LDAP **usually** requires an admin account, called `managerDn` by the Spring LDAP classes. This `managerDN` is usually set when creating the LDAP context source. In your case, the methods to set it are provided by the `contextSource()` builder, to be set as follows:

```
auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns("mail={0},ou=group")
        .groupSearchBase("ou=group")
        .contextSource()

        .managerDN("your admin account's Distinguished Name (DN)")
        .managerPassword("password associated with your admin account")

        .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=ad,dc=company,dc=com")
        .and()
        .passwordCompare()
        .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
        .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
```